# Shell script: Want to find all files in last hour and cat the last 1000 lines to 1 log file

Tags: shell, cat

I'm currently trying to get the last files modified for the hour in a directory and cat them to one static log file.  The problem is I don't know how many files there will be to cat... could be 5, could be 15.  So I'm thinking it'd go something like this but the caveat that I only want probably the last 1000 lines of each file i'm finding... I tried a standard tail with a wild card but got an error saying illegal function or something.

`find /xxy/ -mmin -60 | cat /xxy/*.log > /xxy/static.log`

It works... but if the file is a month old i'm getting everything. I'd like to shorton it to just 1000 entries per log file found but google isn't aiding me at this point and I'm a bit of a beginner.

Any tips or pointers would be great.  But I might have to approach it differently.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `find /xxy/ -mmin -60 -exec tail -1000 {} \;` ?

Comment: @WalterA Looks good to me - you should put it as the answer.

Comment: That might be more efficient than what I came up with.  I'll give it a whirl. Thanks.  When I ran this on the server itself i'm getting an error -exec command not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback, ended up using this:

FILENUM=$(find /xxy/ -mmin -60 | wc -l)

find /xxy/ -type f -name "*"| tail -n$FILENUM | xargs tail -n1000

Answer (score 1):

The only one of these "last hour" of commands that ever worked for me is:

```
find . -mtime -.04
```

Sending that to a file of course could be as easy as:

```
find . -mtime -.04 > static.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I first posted this solution as a comment, I thought I was missing some requirement.
This solution (nlu findinf files with a name like `*.log`) should work

```
find /xxy/ -type f -name "*.log" -mmin -60 -exec tail -1000 "{}" \;
```

OP told (comment on the original question) that this did not work.
His error `-exec command not found` suggests that he had a pipe or semicolon before the `-exec`. When he has a broken `find`, he can try something like

```
find /xxy/ -type f -name "*.log" -mmin -60 -print0 | xargs --null -n1 tail -1000
```

I added -print0 and --null supporting filenames with a newline.